# Inserting a flash into html rich text editor

Tags: asp.net, html, ajax

I created a asp.net page. The ajax rich text editor is contained in these page. Now, I publish the project. In runtime, I want to input a flash file into these text editor. I have found a button for flash input but I not seen this. I try to fill in html view of text editor but It is got an error.

This is filled in html view.

```
<object>
<embed src="../Test/test.swf">
</embed>
</object>
```

how can I solve this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. In the rich text editor, embed tag is not work. Now, I remove it.